# Select and then display mysql row and also tell php what its value is?

Tags: php, mysql

How would I make something select and display a mysql row via php, and also tell the php what its value is? Thanks.

Here's the code I have attempted, but I don't know where to go from there.
I am a HUGE php noob.

```
$notificationchk = "SELECT * FROM notification WHERE username='$_SESSION['username']'";
```

Comment: You need to put more information and try to attempt it first.  There are a million tutorials out there.  We are not going to do the work for you, however we will help with problems.  The problem here is, you haven't tried....

Comment: So all you have tried is building a string?.....

Comment: just go over tutorials on querying in php

Comment: Post your code for connecting to your database. Are you using `mysqli` or `PDO`? If you need help choosing look at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php It shows examples of each, including simple examples of how to echo the result sets.

Answer (score 0):

okay. query crash couse for ya!  Notice that what you wrote is this:
1 - "Create a variable. Call that variable notificationchk. Also, make that variable a string"

2 - Now we have a nice variable, which carries a nice string. Guess what? that string is a message to a function, a function that accesses stuff from a database. That database has tables, as any decent database does. The table youre interested in is called 'notification'

3 - But what is the name of the database? well, I am assuming you already know that because trying to pull data from a table without pointing to a database is kinda never going to work properly unless you are very, VERY lucky... So i am guessing you know what your database is, but i don't, so I'm calling it "STUFF". "STUFF" might have some other tables other than 'notification'. But well, that doesnt concern us here, because we need data from this one table: 'notification'. However, before you can access the table 'notification' in the database STUFF, you need to "point" to that STUFF database. You need the USE command, as in "USE STUFF"...Yes, BEFORE that line you just wrote for us here ;)

4- But hold on... we need a connection to the program that does stuff to databases even BEFORE we try the "USE STUFF" command... but i will assume also that you already know that...

5 - well, see all those nice commands? USE and SELECT. There are others like INSERT and DELETE that you'll also need. The important thing however, is that these ARE NOT PHP COMMANDS. SURPRISE!! Consider them "MySQL commands".

6 - Confusing? well, PHP just passes these commands to the MySQL engine thingy, and that is why they are strings. That nice line you wrote is actually "hey php, can you please create a string called 'notificationchk'?". Now what? now you need ANOTHER php command after that to actually send that string to the MySQL thingy. The command is "mysql_query", and it is a very nice function.

7 - So after that, you'll do this:

$resultOfQuery=mysql_query($notificationchk,$conn)

And that my friend, is a new variable (we called it "$resultOfQuery") that will be the result of the function mysql_query sending the request '$notificationchk' using the connection '$conn' that you must have created before all this took place. You DID use a 'mysql_connect' command before all this, right? In short (hehe) the line you wrote in itself is just a little part of the whole you must learn. But it is not hard at all. If I did it, anybody can :D

8 - i could say more... but I will tell you 2 things: hit the tutorials/books, there is no other way :) thing number 2 is this: ALWAYS CHECK FOR AN ERROR AFTER EVERY, I mean EVERY "query" command you give. Tutorials for beginners might not stress this, but just do it. You'll end up with lots of them and feel very proud you did.

Live long and prosper _\//

Answer (score 0):

you just have a query inside a string and this is not too much. You need to do quite a few things.

Establish a connection with the database first.

$link = mysqli_connect("yourhost", "yourusername", "yourpassword", "yourdatabase");

Then check if there was any error with the connection

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
```

Then you can have a variable to hold your query which you have done, it's nicer to prepare parameterized queries

```
$notificationchk = "SELECT `column1`, `column2` FROM notification WHERE 
username='$_SESSION['username']'";
```

Since you will get some rows back, you need a variable to hold the results

```
$results = mysqli_query($link, $notificationchk) or die(some error message);
```

The above executes the query, if it fails, kills the page and gives an error.

Once you get the result, you want to go through the rows it returned, best done using a while loop

```
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results))
{
    //do whatever you want in here as it loops through the rows
    echo $rows['column1'].' '.$rows['column2'].'<br>';
}
```

This will just print the values of column 1 and 2 on a seperate line for each row returned.

For more info, check the php manual, pretty clear tutorial.

[PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

There might be tutorials where you are inclined to type in google mysql php tutorials but remember that mysql functions are depreciated or are going to be, so make sure the tutorials you view are with the keyword mysqli in them.

If you don't like to read much like me, there is a nice video here

[Video for database connection in php](http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=11&number=113)

watch part 1 and 2, shows good example of connecting to the database and watch the other tuts to see how he queries the db.

Hope this helped.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You need an established connection to the database first. If you are using procedural PHP, then it's created like this:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "test");
mysqli_select_db($connection, "db");
```

After which you do your query:

```
$notificationchk = "SELECT * FROM notification WHERE username='$_SESSION['username']'";
```

then you query that string with:

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $notificationchk);
```

and then iterate through the rows and display them:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['desired_ column_name'] . "<br />";
}
```

That's it. If you want to do it object oriented style, look at the documentation on the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/pl/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php)